# .flat() is not a function, what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, arrays, flat

The following code

```
function steamrollArray(arr) {
  // I'm a steamroller, baby
  return arr.flat();
}

steamrollArray([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]);
```

returns

> `arr.flat` is not a function

I tried it in **Firefox** and **Chrome v67** and the same result has happened.

What's wrong?

Comment: Its [experimental](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat). What browser are you on?

Comment: What browser?  Did you look at the [availability table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)?

Comment: Yes, I have seen it and I tried it in Firefox, when it didn't work, I tried again with Chrome(which is supported, last version) and the same result has happened.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: @TechnoKnight Chrome **69+** is supported.  Which version of Chrome do you have?

Comment: Oops, I have 67 version lol.

Comment: May I ask something, what about freecodecamp console, is it linked to browser or not?

Comment: chrome 69 is not even released as a stable

Comment: It’s also available in Firefox Nightly only, as, again, the documentation on MDN states.

Comment: Oh man! That means that I will have to write the code manually, sigh. Well, thank you a lot though!

Comment: @TechnoKnight Details, details.  :)   As an alternative, you can either implement the method yourself, or use one from a library such as Lodash: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#flattenDeep

Comment: I will just build the method myself. Thank you all for helping me! And sorry for misleading you by saying that I have the latest version of Chrome, well, I thought that I had the latest version(it seems that 69 is not stable, just beta)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The `flat` method is [not yet implemented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Browser_compatibility) in common browsers (only Chrome v69, Firefox Nightly and Opera 56). It’s an experimental feature. Therefore you cannot use it *yet*.

You may want to have your own `flat` function instead:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'flat', {
    value: function(depth = 1) {
      return this.reduce(function (flat, toFlatten) {
        return flat.concat((Array.isArray(toFlatten) && (depth>1)) ? toFlatten.flat(depth-1) : toFlatten);
      }, []);
    }
});

console.log(
  [1, [2], [3, [[4]]]].flat(2)
);
```

The code was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript) by [Noah Freitas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1370576/noah-freitas) originally implemented to flatten the array with no `depth` specified.

Comment: That would be equivalent to `arr.flat(Infinity)`, but not with the default argument of `1`

Comment: @Ivan [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) takes one argument that defines the flattening depth. This polyfill doesn’t.

Comment: Just run your code snippet to test it. Your 4 is still in an array.

Comment: @Matt It should be ([result is `[1,2,3,[4]]` on Chrome v69](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSal5.png)).

Comment: you may want to not use depth-1 as your condition, if you pass in 0, that becomes -1 which is equal to true, and not false.

Comment: @WORMSS, thank you for noticing the error, I corrected it by replacing the condition with `depth > 1`.

Comment: @RotimiBest That's weird. I checked and it works on Chrome v74. Can you try typing `Array.prototype.flat` in your console?

Comment: At the end of 2019 `flat()` is no longer experimental and is supported in all modern browsers (so everywhere except IE and Edge … and it will come to Edge when it switches to the Blink rendering engine in the near future).

Comment: september 2020, still an issue :/

Answer (score 36):

This can also work.

```
let arr = [ [1,2,3], [2,3,4] ];
console.log([].concat(...arr))
```

Or for older browsers,

```
[].concat.apply([], arr);
```

Comment: Very easy, worked for me for a test on Leetcode as array.flat() was not supported in JS

Answer (score 16):

`Array.flat` is not [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Browser_compatibility) by your browser. Below are two ways to implement it.

As a function, the `depth` variable specifies how deep the `input` array structure should be flattened (defaults to 1; use `Infinity` to go as deep as it gets) while the `stack` is the flattened array, passed by reference on recursive calls and eventually returned.

```
function flat(input, depth = 1, stack = [])
{
    for (let item of input)
    {
        if (item instanceof Array && depth > 0)
        {
            flat(item, depth - 1, stack);
        }
        else {
            stack.push(item);
        }
    }
    
    return stack;
}
```

As a Polyfill, extending `Array.prototype` if you prefer the `arr.flat()` syntax:

```
if (!Array.prototype.flat)
{
    Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'flat',
    {
        value: function(depth = 1, stack = [])
        {
            for (let item of this)
            {
                if (item instanceof Array && depth > 0)
                {
                    item.flat(depth - 1, stack);
                }
                else {
                    stack.push(item);
                }
            }
            
            return stack;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: no idea why flat doesn't work in my node v12, anyway thx for flat func, copy and get what i need <3

Answer (score 5):

Similar issue, solved by using ES6 .reduce() method:

```
const flatArr = result.reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr),[]);
```

Comment: It goes only 1 level deep though

Answer (score 2):

use _.flatten from lodash package ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];
var result=[].concat(...arr);
console.log(result);    //output: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution is `_.flattenDeep()` on **lodash**

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flattenDepth

```js
const flatArrays = _.flattenDeep([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]);

console.log(flatArrays);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const array = [
  [
    [6, 6],
    [3, 3],
  ],
  [[7, 7, [9]]],
]

function simplifyArray(array) {
  const result = []

  function recursivePushElem(arr) {
    arr.forEach(i => {
      if (Array.isArray(i)) recursivePushElem(i)
      else result.push(i)
    })
  }
  recursivePushElem(array)

  console.log(result)
  return result
}

simplifyArray(array)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you could simply use this `[].concat(...objArrs)` that would work the same as the `flat()` method and allow more compatibility in browsers

Answer (score 0):

You can set your full array to a string then split it. `.toString().split(',')`

Updated due to community bot.
So basically if you want to flatten out an array that does contain any objects but strictly strings or numbers, by using `.toString()` it converts each element of the array to a string (if it isn't already), and then joins all of the elements together using a comma as a separator.

Once we have our string all separated by a comma we can use `.split()` to create an array.

NOTE*** The reason this wont work with objects is that `.toString()` will return `[object object]` as it is the default string representation of an object in JavaScript.

If your array consists solely of numbers than you would need to map through your array and convert each string number value to a number.

```
const array1 = [
  ['one', 'oneTwo'],
  'two',
  'three',
  'four',
]
console.log('a1', array1.toString().split(','))

const numberArray = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]], [[7, [8,9]]], 10]; 
console.log(numberArray.toString().split(',').map(num => Number(num)));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Not sure if it is a valid answer however in my attemp to flat an array I employed the [destructuring_assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) introduced in ES6.

```js
// typeScriptArray:Array<Object> = new Array<Object>();
let concatArray = [];

let firstArray = [1,2,3];
let secondArray = [2,3,4];

concatArray.push(...firstArray);
concatArray.push(...secondArray);

console.log(concatArray);
```

It works like a charm even though I'm not sure if any broswer compatibily issues may arise.

Comment: You could simply do `concatArray = [...firstArray, ...secondArray]`

Comment: @georg that is even better.