# Array.prototype.flat() is not working in command line using Node JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, flatten, flat

I am trying to test the array.flat method inside Visual Studio code using node js from the command line. When I run the code i get:

> "TypeError: arr.flat is not a function"

I have ran the code in chrome and am able to get the desired result (a flattened array)

Note: Even after updating node js to the latest version, it is still not working.

```js
var arr1 = [1, 2, [3, 4]];
arr1.flat(); 
console.log(arr1)
```

Comment: `.flat()` creates a *new* array and returns it. It does not modify the source array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.flat() is not a function, what's wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50993498/flat-is-not-a-function-whats-wrong)

Comment: When you say you updated Node to the latest version, which version was that?

Comment: @Ry- Node version10.16.3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Only NodeJS version 11 and above support this method. Please note that the current LTS Node version is only at 10.16.3, which does not support this.

Check the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Browser_compatibility).

To check what version use this:

```
node --version
```

If you Node version is below 11, you will need to [upgrade it](https://nodejs.org/en/) to use it.

**Note**

Node versions that use odd number major versions (i.e., v11.x.x, v13.x.x) are generally perceived as a test version and should not be used for production applications. Use even number major versions (i.e., v10.x.x, v12.x.x) instead.

Comment: @TylerMorales: Don’t update to v11, v11 is outdated. The latest Node is 12.9.0.

Comment: @yqlim Thanks for the answer. Would just to add that the command node -v is the short form of node --version, So both can be used :)