# Remove array from data received from an http call - angularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am doing an http call to get data from a database.  There are 6 types that have to be called individually.

```
        $scope.getAll = function() {
        var url = 'http://someurl/';
        varl allObjects = [];
        $scope.types.forEach(element => {
            http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: url + element.name
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                allObjects.push(response.data);
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
               // this doesn't apply to my issue
            });
            $scope.allObjects = allObjects;
            }
```

That return like the following JSON object:

```
[{},

[{ "label":"myLabel",
        "types": {
           "source":{"url":"some url, "storage":"some storage"}}},
     { "label":"myLabel",
        "types": {
           "source":{"url":"some url, "storage":"some storage"}}}],[{ more objects}],[{ more objects}],],
```

All objects return the same structure with nested arrays.  The issue I need help solving is every time it goes through an iteration of the type, it adds it as an array of objects.  I need it to be added just as a new object, not an array of objects.  ie:

What I am getting:

```
[{}, [{first iteration}], [{second iteration}], [{etc}]]
```

What I need:

```
[{first iteration}, {second iteration}, {etc}]
```

Comment: don`t push response.data to allObjects because your response is already in array..
simply assign it to a variable

Comment: @MuhammadFazeel I am pushing it because I need it to append to the array.  If I assign it to a variable, it will get overwritten during the for each method.

Comment: Read up on components and controller as syntax. Any article that includes injecting $scope can be considered out of date.

Comment: @codeandrunningmom Does my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `Array.prototype.flat()` function which compresses an array of arrays to a certain depth level. The depth for your situation would be `1` which is already set as default

```js
var arr = [
   {}, 
   [
     { 
        test: 1 
     }
   ], 
   [ 
     { 
        second: 2 
     }
   ], 
   [
     {
        etc: 3
     }
   ]
];
console.log(arr.flat());
```

The function essentially flattens the arrays in the array, only going in depth of 1, if you had arrays in the arrays you wanted to flatten you'd change the depth to `2`.

The empty object will still be there however. You can make a check to get rid of those after flattening.

Comment: This did not quite solve my issue, since this is a prototype that is not supported by the browser I am using.  But it did send me down a path to finding a solution.  Thank you so much!  This is what I ended up finding:

let arr = [ [1,2,3], [2,3,4] ];
console.log([].concat(...arr))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50993498/flat-is-not-a-function-whats-wrong

It was an answer provided by @R.Cha.  Not sure how to give them proper props and credit.  Thank you to both of you :)